# Opencart - Remove custom extensions from URL (Page ID)

Tags: php, .htaccess, opencart

I have made my site seo friendly. But at the end of the url I want to remove Page ID.

It is coming like `https://example.com/handpainted-tees?page=2`. I want it to be like `https://example.com/handpainted-tees`.

Can any one suggest me where to do the same?

Comment: you want every `page` to have the same url?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using this rule in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^handpainted-tees$ /handpainted-tees?page=2 [L]
```

This will remove the custom extensions and leave you with the URL: `https://example.com/handpainted-tees`. Make sure you clear your cache before you test this.